# Angular5: Passing Variable From One Component to Another Typescript File

Tags: angular, typescript, input

I am trying to pass the value I am storing in one of my components to another component so that my new component can use the selected value from my original. Right now I have a file as follows:

**symbol-picker.component.ts**

```js
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-symbol-picker',
  templateUrl: './symbol-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./symbol-picker.component.scss']
})

export class SymbolPickerComponent implements OnInit {

  selectionChoice: string;

  equalsTxt = '=';
  impliesTxt = '=>';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Where I am setting the value of 'selectionChoice' in my html as follows:

**symbol-picker.component.html**

```html
<button (click)="selectionChoice = 'equals'">{{equalsTxt}}</button>
<button (click)="selectionChoice = 'implies'">{{impliesTxt}}</button>
```

I want to pass the value held in 'selectionChoice' to a new file to use it. For instance I am trying to get the value right now in this file:

**symbolPicker.ts**

```js
import {SymbolPickerComponent} from '../symbol-picker/symbol-picker.component';

export interface Config {
  container: string;
  selector: 'equals'|'implies'|'followsFrom';
}

export interface QuillInstance {
  on: Function;
  getText: Function;
}

export default class SymbolPicker {
  symbolSelected = SymbolPickerComponent.selectionChoice;
  quill: QuillInstance;
  options: Config;

  constructor(quill, options) {
    this.quill = quill;
    this.options = options;

    const container = document.querySelector(this.options.container);

    switch (this.options.selector) {
      case 'equals': {
        container.addEventListener('click', function() {
          console.log('FRANK: EQUALS PRESSED');
          quill.insertText(quill.getSelection(), '\n=            〈  〉');
        });
        break;
      }
      case 'implies': {
        container.addEventListener('click', function() {
          console.log('FRANK: IMPLIES PRESSED');
          quill.insertText(quill.getSelection(), '\n=>            〈  〉');
        });
        break;
      }
      default: {
        console.log('FRANK: selectionChoice set to non-understood value');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I set my newly declared 'symbolSelected' variable in symbolPicker.ts to the value of selectionChoice in symbol-picker.component.ts? I am ultimate trying to do this so in my editor.components.ts file I can reference this value as well for my 'selector' section in symbolPicker as follows:

```js
this.modules = {
      formula: true,
      toolbar: true,
      counter: { container: '#counter', unit: 'word' },
      symbolPicker: { container: '#symbolCounter', selector: this.symbolSelected }
    };
```

The idea would be that this selector value would dynamically change as I press the buttons to change between 'equals' and 'implies'.

Comment: Use for that @Input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to share data between components. For your particular scenario, your best choice is a service. Build a service to retain the value(s) that you want to share.

Then inject the service into any component that needs to set the value or read the value.

I have an example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-communication/tree/master/MH-Take4

In my case, I share the currently selected movie. Below are some snippets of my code. (See the above URL for the complete code example.)

**Movie service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class MovieService {

    currentMovie: IMovie | null;
    // Other code here.
}
```

**Movie List component**

In this component, the user selects a movie:

```
export class MovieListComponent {
    constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

    onSelected(movie: IMovie): void {
        this.movieService.currentMovie = movie;
    }
    // Other code here
}
```

**Movie Detail component**

In this component, the bindings change automatically when the user selects a different movie in the Movie List component.

The UI is bound to the `movie` property defined in the component below.

```
export class MovieDetailComponent {

    get movie(): IMovie | null {
        return this.movieService.currentMovie;
    }

    constructor(private movieService: MovieService) {}
}
```

Angular's change detection tracks when the `currentMovie` changes in the service and rebinds the values, calling the getter shown above, and getting the current value of the `currentMovie`.

Comment: Thanks for the  response I wasn't sure what the best way to tackle the problem was but a service makes sense